# VBA, Print variable/array to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to debug and print my variable (`Debug.Print`), but there is over 4000 values which i dont want to step through using f8 to find what I'm looking for. If I f5 through the variable, the immediate window does not let me see all values.

my code is like so:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(irShocks, 1)
    irShocks(i, 1) = irShocks(i, 3) & "|" & irShocks(i, 2) 
    Debug.Print irShocks(i, 1)
    Worksheets("NewSheetName2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(irShocks(i, 1), 1), UBound(irShocks(i, 1), 2)).value = irShocks(i, 1)
Next i
```

I get a `type mismatch` when trying to print my variable to a new sheet. `Debug.Print` works fine.

How can I print all these values into a new sheet to view them all at once?

Comment: `Worksheets("NewSheetName").Range("A1").Resize(ubound(ArrayVar,1),ubound(ArrayVar,2)).Value = ArrayVar`

Comment: Do I make `ArrayVar` my variable name?

Comment: yes, I had to guess as you did not tell us the name, or provide any code that would make this a truly answerable question.

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry.

Comment: my line would go outside the loop.

Comment: and remove the `(i,1)` in both Ubounds.